# How to count row of a table from sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to count rows of a table in android.I used 2 ways but not success & get a warning message

```
Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
 Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44e26a30 com.india.screen/.CategoryList}
```

I have tried-

```
String query="Select count(*) from Holyplace_Tbl";
```

1. **Using rawQuery**

   public void countRows(String query) {

   ```
   Cursor mcursor = assetDatabaseHelper.executeQuery(query);
   mcursor.moveToFirst();
   int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
   System.out.println("NUMBER IN DB: " + icount);
   mcursor.close();
   ```

   }
2. **Using DatabaseUtils**

   ```
   public int countRows(String query)
   {

      int sometotal = (int) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(sqliteDatabaseObj, query, null);
     return sometotal;
    }
   ```

   [AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244881/how-solve-launch-timeout-has-expired-giving-up-wake-lock-in-android)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try This

```
private static final String DB_TABLE_PLACES = "Places";
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

private long fetchPlacesCount() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DB_TABLE_PLACES;
    SQLiteStatement statement = mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
    long count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
    return count;
}
```

See More [Here](http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-get-number-of-rows-in-sqlite-database-table/).

Comment: I still have same warning message & get no value.

Comment: No, I Get it . see i have one tabel name is test with 2 rows .Perfectly run for me. see your code . use this method as public.I just copy this function in my db code and edit with public and call in main activity and print in toast. so may be any other problem in your code.

Comment: 11-07 12:45:12.534: D/dalvikvm(92): GC freed 16379 objects / 524312 bytes in 55ms only these lines show in log if call function on button click,otherwise warning message

Comment: where you put this function ? and how did you call it ?

Comment: I put it in AssetDatabaseOpenHelper class

Comment: my second que how did you call it >

Comment: public long fetchPlacesCount(String query) {
     
     SQLiteStatement statement = sqliteDatabaseObj.compileStatement(query);
     long count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
     System.out.println("rows are"+count);
     return count;
 }

Comment: holyPlaces.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
    String query="Select count(*) from Holyplace_Tbl";
   
   long a= assetDatabaseHelper.fetchPlacesCount(query);
   System.out.println("long......"+a);
   }
  });

Comment: try this way SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DB_TABLE // main check your table name. replace your query with this query.

Comment: I add fetchPlacesCount in AssetDatabaseopenHelper.i call it CategoryList Activity from AssetDatabaseopenHelper.

Comment: did you change that by my query ?

Comment: i try your query but count not print.I get a lot message GC freed 16378 objects / 524280 bytes in 120ms in logcat

Comment: have you try any other table /.

Comment: yes, but same problem for cont,but sql with limitfor getting value from table success.

Comment: i think mukesh there is some other problem ? how many rows currently added in your table ?

Comment: 200,400 but if apply condition then also same proplem.

Comment: can you try for only two or three data ?

Comment: when System.gc() add in code then num of rows shows,but when click on another button then same problem.

Comment: then there was something db problem . because its working for me as well as you but with some problem.

Comment: GC freed 314 objects / 12856 bytes in 118ms logcat fills with this message

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273735/android-gc-logcat-always-showing-gc-activity

Answer (score 4):

Simplest and Efficient way that i found from [How to count number of records in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438482/1318946)

> [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) provides Static utility methods for dealing with
>   databases and Cursors.

```
int numRows = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name", null);
```

Or:

```
int numRows = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "table_name");
```

Comment: `queryNumEntries` is meant for this!

Comment: Is "DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries" still a good choice or has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple RawQuery like this:

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

Cursor c = mDatabase.rawQuery("select COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME",null);

int count = c.getCount();
```

The `Cursor.getCount()` method returns the number of rows in the cursor, whch in this case would be the number of items you are looking for.

Comment: Cursor.getCount() returns no of columns in cursor not row.

Comment: rows are horizontal and columns are vertical in a table. It returns no of rows. I'm sure you are mistaken. Please check again

Comment: @Mukesh.  getCount definitely returns number of rows,  Are you sure that you do not by coincidence have the same number of rows as you have columns?

Comment: @AnupCowkur yes,tables consists 200  to 400 rows

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29

Answer (score 0):

```
long numRows = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, table);
```

Comment: Is "DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries" still a good choice or has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You can get row count as follows:

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Your_tabename", null);
int i = c.getCount();
```